# storm caching in topology level available for all bolts

Tags: caching, apache-storm

,but I need cache to retrieve the data from database and put it in cache.So the I compare the cache with incoming tuples.Based on that I can proceed to next.That cache should be refreshed based on given time .What cache should I implement,so that all bolts use that single cache.
NOTE:If I implement cache in bolt level the bolts are executed in each machine.So that all bolts are maintain each cache.So that I need topology level so that all bolts uses single cache.
If anyone know this tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **tick tuples** for it. Please, see an article below it describes all that you needed.
http://kitmenke.com/blog/2014/08/04/tick-tuples-within-storm/

Comment: Thanks Man ,but I need cache to retrieve the data from database and put it in cache.So the I compare the cache with incoming tuples.Based on that I can proceed to next.That cache should be refreshed based on given time .What cache should I implement,so that all bolts use that single cache

Comment: @kartik So, in my view in this case you should have a dedicated machine with cache and special piece of code for cache population from database. It will be executed by schedule. [Redis](http://redis.io/) is very useful here. After it all your bolts will go to the single cache.

Comment: Thank you very much Ilya Lapitan for your reply.It worked for me